# getApprovalLink method from Paypal API SDK returns live link instead of sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm experiencing a very odd problem using PayPal REST API PHP SDK.

Just recently when my code was fine for sandbox and without a problem, it suddenly stopped working. The only thing I tried was to change Client ID and Secret from sandbox to live. Then I saw going live tutorial and decided to roll back to sandbox for a while (Of course using the sandbox client id and secret).

Now when I make purchases as sandbox, PayPal returns `getApprovalLink()` this way:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=TOKEN_GENERATED_BY_PAYPAL
```

When adding sandbox as sub-domain it works perfectly. It should return this way:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=TOKEN_GENERATED_BY_PAYPAL
```

(As it was returning before I did what I mentioned above.)

I've checked my git commits, nothing unusual, I re-installed PayPal REST API with composer, checked whether everything is set to sandbox. Everything seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is a paypal issue. It's not a bug in the sdk. Paypal team is working on it. All you can do is just wait until they're finished.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/650

Edit: should be working again.